# Can silver antiseize affect ABS sensors?

Tags: brakes, abs

I recently did a full brake pad and rotor job on my Kia Sorento 2011 and it turned out well. No real issues. However I am now getting a few warning lights on my car that is indicating an issue with the ABS sensors. I used Silver anti-seize on the back of the brake pads as well as on the contact points between the clips and the brake pads (just those little tabs on the brake pads). After the fact i've read a couple [places](https://greaseexpert.com/brake-grease-vs-anti-seize/) that copper or aluminum anti-seize can have a negative affect on the ABS sensors. My question is that is that likely the case or is it a coincidence the ABS sensor has failed/having issues? And if it is a potential cause what should i replace the aluminum anti seize with? I was having some slight squeaking so thats part of why I want to use something on the metal to metal contact points (I did not use it on the caliper pins, used sil-glyde there)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, no, the anti-seize will not affect the ABS sensor. You shouldn't have been anywhere near where the ABS sensor is at ... well, that may be an over statement, however, unless you removed the ABS sensor from the housing, you shouldn't have gotten any anti-seize sensor or reluctor ring. If I were you, I'd double check the connections of the sensors by disconnecting and reconnecting them, which should be within a foot of where the sensor connects to hub. Beyond that, it's something else going on. Scanning the ABS system may be a good route to go with it (which most generic code readers will NOT do).

Comment: I actually just ordered the Blue Driver ODB2 scanner so should be able to read this code. Question (which you answered) was more if i should strip the anti-seize off but looks like it is not causing the issue

Comment: Unless it specifically states it will read SRS or ABS, it won't do it. Cursory glance at the Bluedriver, it DOES NOT read SRS or ABS codes.

Comment: Taking a second look ... I take that back. Looks like it does.